# Change pages dynamically on click in the same view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a clone of Spotify more-less. At this time what I want to achieve is to make on click event on menu span items which on click will show a container a page where some content will be visible. 
On my aside bar I added the span with the pages to point and added to HTML the pages with data-page as an anchor for it. I also make a jquery event.

What I did is as follow regarding the Jquery:

```
$(".menu .sb-item span").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    $(".main .page:not('.hide')")
      .stop()
      .fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).addClass("hide");
        $('.main .page[data-page="' + page + '"]')
          .fadeIn("slow")
          .removeClass("hide");
      });
  });
```

I have a working version simplified [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jakub41/wf92xoa5/5/) of what I want to achieve on JSFiddle.

Clicking on the span you will see the pages change.

Now my issue is that on my page where I implemented this is not working at all [my example page](https://jakub41.github.io/spotify-bs4-clone/)

On the console clicking on the span I have the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stop is not a function
```

I cannot resolve this issue as on JSFiddle it is working so I cannot see why is not on my page.

Comment: Looks like you are using a slim version of jquery which is excluding the methods related to effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Taplar, if you want to slim version here i changed some modifications

```
$(function(){
        $(".menu .sb-item span").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    $(".main").find('#'+page).fadeIn("slow").siblings().fadeOut("fast");
});    
    })
```